# Filtering One Dropdown box and not the other that share the same API ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've run into an External API Data Fetching issue where there are 2 `<select>` inputs that are getting data from a URL that looks like this `/jobs/dataId=44.`

So when this URL is fetched, options specific to `dataId=44` are populating both of these dropdowns.

I am filtering this data through a controller that makes the service calls based on the `dataId` that is passed via a GET request.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetFilteredData(int? id, string term, int? page)
        {
           NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.AddCustomParameter("params", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ID = id, Term = term, Page = page }));                   

           IEnumerable<JobChoice> choices;           

            if (id.Value == JobQuestionID)
            {
                var work_places = GetWorkMatches(term, null);
                choices = work_places.Select(x => new JobChoice { ChoiceText = x.Name, Id = Convert.ToUInt32(x.ChoiceID) });
            }
            else
            {

            // This is where I'm writing a condition to filter the dropdowns
                    if (id == 44)
                    {                                                    
                                // Only show Supported Jobs
                                var jobcodes = new List<uint> {1,2,3,4,5};

                                choices = _jobAdapter.FetchQuestionChoices(id.Value)
                                    .Select(x => _jobChoiceTransformer.Transform(x))
                                    .Where(x => x != null && !jobcodes.Contains(x.Id));                                
                     }                     


                    else
                    {
                        var searchTerm = JobChoiceConverter.Scrub(term);
                        choices = _jobAdapter.FetchQuestionChoices(id.Value)[searchTerm]
                            .Select(x => _jobChoiceTransformer.Transform(x))
                            .Where(x => x != null);


                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
                        {
                            var jobChoices = choices.OrderBy(x => x.ScrubbedChoiceText);
                            var choicesThatStartWithTerm = jobChoices.Where(x => x.ScrubbedChoiceText.StartsWith(searchTerm)).ToList();
                            var choicesThatContainTerm = jobChoices.Where(x => x.ScrubbedChoiceText.Contains(searchTerm) && !choicesThatStartWithTerm.Contains(x));
                            choices = choicesThatStartWithTerm.Concat(choicesThatContainTerm);
                        }

                    }                

            }

                var choicesArray = choices.ToArray();
                if (!page.HasValue)
                    return PagedJson(choicesArray, 1, Int32.MaxValue);
                return PagedJson(choicesArray, page.Value, PageSize);

        }
```

So you can see the problem is that both of these dropdowns are sharing the same Id when the GET request is made.  I just want to know if there is some clever approach to write an IF condition in this scenario where I can filter one dropdown and NOT the other.

**EDIT:**

The client-side code is using CoffeeScript to generate the dropdown boxes.  Here is what the code looks like:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
new Question.JobChoice
        name: 'Jobs'
        questionText: 'Select jobs that you have.'
        maximumSelectionSize: 5
        questionID: 44

new Question.JobChoice
        name: 'SupportedPrimaryJob'
        questionText: 'What is your primary job (required)?'
        maximNCumSelectionSize: 1
        choiceID: 'Primary_Job_Choice'
        skipLogic: (context) -> PrimaryJobSkip(context)
        validateLogic: (validator, context) -> PrimaryJobValidate(validator, context, 'Primary Job Required')
        questionID: 44
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It'd be pretty useful if you added your client-side code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I worked around this issue was by adding an additional parameter to this constructor and then I eventually passed it into the URL.  Once I passed it into the URL, I was able to grab this additional parameter via the GET request and distinguish the 2 dropdown fields.